# Log4j2 main ERROR AmazonRollingRandomAccessFile contains an invalid element or attribute

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to use `Log4j2` in my application and my relevant configuration looks like below code:

```
*.*.log4j2.appender.file.type = RollingRandomAccessFile;
*.*.log4j2.appender.file.name = file;
*.*.log4j2.appender.file.fileName = "$ROOT/var/output/logs/$APP";
*.*.log4j2.appender.file.filePattern = "$ROOT/var/output/logs/$APP.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}";
*.*.log4j2.appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout;
*.*.log4j2.appender.file.layout.pattern = "%d{DATE} [%p] %X{requestId} (%t) %c: %m%n";
```

But, when i run my program i get this error:

```
955 main ERROR RollingRandomAccessFile contains an invalid element or attribute "fileName"
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `*.*.log4j2` prefix may be related. Can you try without this, like in the [example in the log4j2 manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties)?

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingRandomAccessFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```